# Userdata powershell script does not map network drive at instance launch time

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, user-data, amazon-fsx

I have a simple user data script that is executed on an EC2 instance part of an ECS cluster.
Recently, I added the bottom section which tries to map a network drive (FSx) storage to the instance:

user data ps1 script:

```
<powershell>
Import-Module ECSTools
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ECS_ENABLE_AWSLOGS_EXECUTIONROLE_OVERRIDE", $TRUE, "Machine")
Initialize-ECSAgent -Cluster "${cluster_name}" -EnableTaskIAMRole -LoggingDrivers '["json-file","awslogs"]' -EnableTaskENI

echo "map the FSx storage drive"
net use D: "\\server.mydomain\share" "/USER:mydomain\myuser" "mypassword" "/PERSISTENT:YES"
</powershell>
```

The problem is that when the EC2 instance launches, the "D" drive is not mapped at all when listing all drives in the system using `gdr -PSProvider 'FileSystem'` command:
[image]

That said, when I execute the user data script manually (i.e. remote connect to the instance), it works and I can see the D:/ drive being mapped:

```
powershell C:\Windows\TEMP\UserScript.ps1
```

[image]

I don't see any errors in the `C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Log\UserdataExecution.log` file either. I see the `echo` text from my script that is not followed by any errors:

```
...
2021-12-15T12:32:05Z - [INFO]:ScheduledTask Initialize-ECSHostReboot created.
2021-12-15T12:32:05Z - [INFO]:Task IAM role is enabled. Changing AmazonECS service startup to Manual.
map the FSx storage drive
The command completed successfully.

2021/12/15 12:32:06Z: Userdata execution done
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you are pro'ly seeing a different account or session. if the failing method creates a drive map ... that map is for that account. if the drive does not show in your other situation ... then you likely are using a different account.

Comment: That is a good point, @Lee_Dailey. The service executing the user-data script might be using a different account that the one I use to remote connect to the EC2 instance. I will investigate further.

Comment: good luck! [*grin*]